# Python boto3 - iam userlist limits to 100 users

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-iam

I was working on a script to filter some users out of all iam user in the same account. It worked fine on one aws account, but when i used same script on another aws account with abuot 400+ users, it just skipped all users after first 100.

I assumed that something is limiting this, so i created below script which counts the number of users in given aws account. it stops at 100 and skips the rest of the users.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import boto3

def main():
    Usercount = 0

    iam = boto3.client('iam')
    client = boto3.client('iam',aws_access_key_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX, aws_secret_access_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)

    try:
        for user in client.list_users()['Users']:
            Usercount +=1
        print(Usercount)
    except:
        print("Error getting user count")
```

This prints right number if iam users are less than 100 but prints only 100 if users are more than 100. **Is there a limit set via aws console? Is there a way to get rid of this limit?**

Comment: Side-note: You should not be hard-coding AWS credentials in your code. Instead, store them in a credentials file. You can use the AWS CLI `aws configure` command to create the credentials file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling `list_users()`, if `IsTruncated` is True, then you should make a subsequent call with `Marker` equal to the value that was returned in the call.

Or, you can simply use a [paginator](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Paginator.ListUsers) that will do it for you:

```py
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_users')

response_iterator = paginator.paginate()

for user in response_iterator:
  Usercount += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a while loop and validate the response for the existence of the marker.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.list_users

Marker (string) -- Use this parameter only when paginating results and only after you receive a response indicating that the results are truncated. Set it to the value of the Marker element in the response that you received to indicate where the next call should start.